mathjax on RSS feed
I try to get update from RSS feed from arxiv.org and zbMATH.org, say math.CO and MSC_05.
In particular, the arxiv feed use $\alpha$ for inline math and $$\alpha$$ for display math, while the zbMATH feed use \(\alpha\) for inline math and \[\alpha\] for display math.
I tried different solutions to read math RSS feed, but none of them is satisfactory.
So far I find the following two partial solutions.

Feedbro plugin for firefox and Chrome
There is the mathjax option. However it only works in Chrome but not in Firefox. And it only renders the $\alpha$ formulae but not the \(\alpha\) formulae.

MathJaX bookmark
I add the ChatJax bookmark in MathJaX bookmarklet v1 and MathJaX bookmark in MathJaX bookmarklet v3. The former renders the $\alpha$ formulae but not the \(\alpha\) formulae repeatly in a webpage, and the latter renders both the $\alpha$ formulae and the \(\alpha\) formulae once in a webpage. I can use both on feedly.com. Since the feedly webpage is dynamic, both bookmark are not perfect. And none of them works in the Feedbro plugin.


I hope to get both the $\alpha$ formulae and the \(\alpha\) formulae rendered correctly. A modified version of Feedbro plugin for Firefox (which I prefer to Chrome) would be perfect. A bookmark renders both formulae are also desirable, but the feedly does not update frequently enough. If there are other solutions, it will be nice as well.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
